# How to superimpose my color below my text

Tags: html, css

I have a table with several `cell`, when i selected a `cell` i put a `color`.

In this exemple i want to put 104.00€ over it the color

[image]

My question is if it's possible to superimpose my color below my text..?
Is there some way to do this?

***my css***:

```
.matrices .selected td{
border-bottom: 3px solid #E05206;
background-color: #c1f928;
```

}

Comment: can you share how you are adding the color to the selected cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will do my best to answer this. I apologize if I interpreted your question incorrectly.

I am assuming you wish to place text on top of a colored cell. I assume you are asking how you can color that `cell`? You can do this one of 2 ways:

Within your HTML (though inline settings are not recommended):

`<td class="selected" bgcolor="#FF0000">January</td>`

Or within your CSS
`.selected {background-color: #ff0000}`

Comment: yu are understand my question but when i set background-color and when i selected cell, the backgroung not change ..?

Comment: make sure you set the `background-color` or the 'class="selected"` on the `<td>`

Comment: @ochi i update my post, there is nothing

Comment: @Mercer this code `.matrices .selected td` is not the right selector for what you want to achieve.  If anything, it would be close to: `.matrices td.selected`